# Flutter awesome notifications how to fix StateError (Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting this error when I have signed out from my flutter app and trying to log in again:

**StateError (Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.)**

The code that gives me this error is on my first page:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((notification) async {
      if (notification.channelKey == 'scheduled_channel') {
        var payload = notification.payload['payload'];
        var value = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(widget.user.uid)
            .doc(payload)
            .get();
        navigatorKey.currentState.push(PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => DetailPage(
                user: widget.user,
                i: 0,
                docname: payload,
                color: value.data()['color'].toString(),
                createdDate: int.parse((value.data()['date'].toString())),
                documentId: value.data()['documentId'].toString(),)));
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

And on another page that contains the sign out code.

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
 if (!mounted) return;
 Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,
 "/login", (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

What can I do to solve this? Is it possible to stop listen to actionstream when I log out? Or should I do it in another way?

Comment: `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` is disposing the state, when you pop the route it calls init again, convert the `.actionStream` to a broadcast type or use the `Navigator.pushNamed`.

Comment: Okay. I tried Navigator.pushNamed. But still same error. How can I convert it to a broadcast?

Comment: You can use the [StreamController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController/StreamController.broadcast.html) or complicate it a bit more and use the [StreamSubscription](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamSubscription-class.html) with the `onData`.

Comment: Okay. I have checked many different examples but I don’t know how to implement that. Do you have any ideas how to start?

Comment: I usually play with the [DartPad](https://www.dartpad.dev) just to get a feel of how something may end up working and if it is not working not much is lost, a few hundred lines may end up saving dozens of hours of fixing. If you are not that familiar with flutter one thing that i would recommend is to just pick widgets and just using them by themselves in some imaginary case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams over all are single use, they replace the callback hell that that ui is, at first a single use streams can seem useless but that may be for a lack of foresight. Over all (at lest for me) flutter provides all the necessary widgets to not get messy with streams, you can find them in the *Implementers* section of [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) and all of those implement others like `TextEditingController`.

With that, an ideal (again, at least for me) is to treat widgets as clusters where streams just tie them in a use case, for example, the widget `StreamBuilder` is designed to *build* on demand so it only needs something that pumps changes to make a *"live object"* like in a clock, a periodic function adds a new value to the stream and the widget just needs to listen and update.

To fix your problem you can make `.actionStream` fit the case you are using it or change a bit how are you using it (having a monkey patch is not good but you decide if it is worth it).

This example is not exactly a *"this is what is wrong, fix it"*, it is more to showcase a use of how `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` and `StreamSubscription` can get implemented. I also used a `InheritedWidget` just because is so useful in this cases. One thing you should check a bit more is that the variable `count` does not stop incrementing when `route_a` is not in focus, the stream is independent and it will be alive as long as the widget is, which in your case, rebuilding the listening widget is the error.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

const String route_a = '/route_a';
const String route_b = '/route_b';
const String route_c = '/route_c';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  Stream<int> gen_nums() async* {
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      yield 1;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return ReachableData(
      child: MaterialApp(
        initialRoute: route_a,
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          route_a: (_) => Something(stream: gen_nums()),
          route_b: (_) => FillerRoute(),
          route_c: (_) => SetMount(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ReachableData extends InheritedWidget {
  final data = ReachableDataState();

  ReachableData({super.key, required super.child});

  static ReachableData of(BuildContext ctx) {
    final result = ctx.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<ReachableData>();
    assert(result != null, 'Context error');
    return result!;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(ReachableData old) => false;
}

class ReachableDataState {
  String? mount;
}

// route a
class Something extends StatefulWidget {
  // If this widget needs to be disposed then use the other
  // constructor and this call in the routes:
  // Something(subscription: gen_nums().listen(null)),

  // final StreamSubscription<int> subscription;
  // Something({required this.subscription, super.key});

  final Stream<int> stream;
  Something({required this.stream, super.key});

  @override
  State<Something> createState() => _Something();
}

class _Something extends State<Something> {
  int count = 0;

  void increment_by(int i) => setState(
        () => count += i,
      );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.stream.listen(increment_by);
    // To avoid any funny errors you should set the subscription
    // on pause or the callback to null on dispose
    // widget.subscription.onData(increment_by);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    var mount = ReachableData.of(ctx).data.mount ?? 'No mount';
    return Scaffold(
      body: InkWell(
        child: Text('[$count] Push Other / $mount'),
        onTap: () {
          ReachableData.of(ctx).data.mount = null;
          Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(route_b);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// route b
class FillerRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const FillerRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InkWell(
        child: Text('Go next'),
        // Option 1: go to the next route
        // onTap: () => Navigator.of(ctx).pushNamed(route_c),

        // Option 2: go to the next route and extend the pop
        onTap: () => Navigator.of(ctx)
            .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(route_c, ModalRoute.withName(route_a)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// route c
class SetMount extends StatelessWidget {
  const SetMount({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: InkWell(
        child: Text('Set Mount'),
        onTap: () {
          ReachableData.of(ctx).data.mount = 'Mounted';
          // Option 1: pop untill reaches the correct route
          // Navigator.of(ctx).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(route_a));

          // Option 2: a regular pop
          Navigator.of(ctx).pop();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```